# how to analyze an XML file?

Tags: java, xml

I have java service that should receive an xml file containing several elements. i need to analyze this file extract matched elements and send them to their related services.

I hope to find a light way to do that as it's a heavy XML file.

Anyone knows a java framework or solution which can help to perform that ?

Thanks

Comment: How large is the file? (file size, # of elements).  If it's going over the wire in a web service, it should be too big (<25Mb). Regular XML DOM parsers work for most files up to 25Mb, after that consider SAX.  It would have to be a huge file (>1Tb) to exceed SAX capabilities.

Comment: try vtd-xml and you won't be disappointed by it.

Answer (score 1):

XPath might be a good solution for this.  Here is a link to the API documentation, but you'll also be able to find many different tutorials and getting started guides.  Just search Google for "Java XPath tutorial" or similar.

http://download.oracle.com/javase/1,5.0/docs/api/javax/xml/xpath/package-summary.html

There are probably several other implementations of XPath that may be better suited for your needs, so it would be worth looking at other open source implementations.

Comment: He'd need to have a way of applying the XPath expression, though. And using XPath directly in Java usually means building a DOM, which would incur a heavy memory penalty for a large XML document.

Comment: Yes i want to avoid unmarshalling the XML file into java objects as it will use a lot of memory

Comment: I don't know a ton about the Java XPath APIs, but I don't think all implementations of XPath require you to load the entire XML graph into memory all at once.  XPath at the core really doesn't require for you to load the entire input or output into memory all at once, so that may just be an implementation detail.  The XPath impl in the Java SDK may do something like that, but you may be able to find impls that work better for large input files.  My answer was  intended to suggest an option to look at, there may be performance implications that would lead you to look for something else.

Answer (score 1):

There are dozens of ways to read an XML file in Java. There are several ones to do it just with Java SE :

- SAX
- DOM
- StAX
- JAXB

Google for them : you'll find documentation and tutorials. The [api doc](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/) is also helpful. You'll find all these tools in package names.

Comment: Thanks JB, SAX and STAX seems interesting

Answer (score 0):

[Apache Commons Digester](http://commons.apache.org/digester)

Define your custom rules to read xml file, and invoke methods or create Objects to unmarshalling.

```
/students/student -> new Student();
/students/student/name -> invoke setName(name) for student
/students/student -> invoke addStudent(student) for each student
```

everything is optional, and you define that need

test with http://commons.apache.org/digester, 
[example](http://www.javaworld.com/javaworld/jw-10-2002/jw-1025-opensourceprofile.html?page=2) in http://www.javaworld.com/javaworld/jw-10-2002/jw-1025-opensourceprofile.html?page=2 and [example](http://www.theserverside.com/news/1364926/Using-The-Digester-Component).

Answer (score 0):

Pass it through an XSLT stylesheet. Java XSLT implementations are really good, keeping the input tree to a minimum and often using (at least by default) bytecode compilation instead of interpreting to make the transformation really fast. Matching input and producing the desired output is exactly what XSLT is suitable for, with its declarative style.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to get the DOM tree of the XML file and then you can use [this](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/XML/DemoTreeWalker.htm) recursive method to go through the tree to find what you want.

Comment: This will work, but if the XML is indeed heavy, the DOM tree might be too much for the VM memory.

Comment: yeah, i guess you're quite right. sorry achraf.

Answer (score 0):

Use [JDOM](http://www.jdom.org/downloads/index.html), it's small, fast, and easy to use.

Answer (score 0):

Try [VTD-XML](http://vtd-xml.sourceforge.net/), it is much faster than JDOM (upto 10x), and DOM4J or DOM, and also memory efficient. see the [VTD-XML Wikipedia Entry](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/VTD-XML) for more Info